# Tangle and transaction explorer

Tags: tangle, iri-legacy-api

I want to have an isolated tangle for testing purposes. I want to explore and browse this tangle for individual transactions, as I attach new transactions on this tangle. **Is there an open source tanlge Explorer?**

Comment: There is https://github.com/peterwilli/IOTA-tangle-explorer, but I never tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one. You should consider that Explorers are Snapshot proof (which means that they connect to permanodes). Developing your own Explorer should not be that hard if you have some programming skills. You could use the [Javascript Lib](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/) and just put a search field for addresses/hashses that could be checked by using the [findTransactionObjects()](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/#findtransactionobjects) method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since this function takes Transaction Hashes as argument, how can I browse starting from zero-knowledge about it's transactions?